# Get file names from specific input using Java Servlet 3.0

Tags: java, file-upload, servlet-3.0

Using Java Servlet 3.0 file upload, how can I get the names of files when I only know the name of the input?
For instance, I will have several inputs which are type="file", and will have the multiple attribute. At the time I'll need the file names, I'll know the input name, but I won't know the file names. I know how to get a file name from the header with substring, I just don't know how to get it from a specific input. It doesn't matter what order I get the filenames, I just need them from the correct input and put into an array for later processing. I've been stuck on this for about 3 weeks and can't find an answer, which probably means I'm looking for the wrong thing.

My inputs will be like this:

```
<input type="file" name="pic1" multiple="multiple">
<input type="file" name="pic2" multiple="multiple">
<input type="file" name="pic3" multiple="multiple">
```

Comment: Does anyone have time to help me with this?

Comment: The real problem is that I don't know how to use the header information. There's numerous examples of how to get file names from the headers, but I can't find anything which will tell me how to only get file names from a specific input, when there are multiple inputs of type "file". I don't need a lot of help, just a nudge in the right direction and I'll take it from there.

Comment: I think I got it. BalusC's MultipartMap actually does what I'm looking for. I just have to make some changes my processing servlet so I can use it.

Comment: Well,I still believe there must be a way to do this purely with java, but I can't figure it out. I have no issues getting the file names from the header, but they are useless if I don't know which input they were uploaded from. I did find a suitable solution though. Since I do know which input the files are uploaded from before I upload them, I wrote a simple JavaScript function to set the file names in hidden inputs. I hard coded it for the maximum number of files, which is 12, but I'm exploring changing it to use files.length instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### And the code:

```
function setFileNames(arg, num){
    for (c=0; c<=11;c++){
    var d = c+1;
    var key = arg.getAttribute('id');
    var number = key.charAt(key.length-1);
    var FileName = document.getElementById("FileName" + d + "-" + number);
    var f = document.getElementById("pic" + number);
    var name = f.files.item(c).name;
        FileName.value = name;


        }return;
    }
```